# Views - Rewrite Content:Link field based on content type

Tags: nodes, views

I'm using Content:Link as a field in a view to make a link button in a list of content. How can I rewrite the results based on content type?

For instance, if the content type is an Article, it would say "Read More" but if it's a Product Display, it would say "Buy Now".

Thanks!
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [Views Conditional Field](https://drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module for this. Based on condition show other field which will output different text.

Module page explains :

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> ```
> Equal To
> Not Equal To
> Greater Than
> Less Than
> Empty
> Not Empty
> ```
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

Comment: i have used that module in the past and totally forgot about it! thank you. :)